# Where to learn math and physics?

Tags: teaching, learning

I have been looking around to find a place where I can advance my knowledge of these two subjects, so far I have found most places suggest "Khan Academy" but I am really bad at learning from videos and I can never get the hang of it.
Do you know any other places I could go to?

Comment: "Shopping questions", i.e. asking for program recommendations, are off-topic on Academia.SE.

Comment: You are not alone.  Some people do NOT do well in this kind of pedagogical environment.  For such people, there are colleges, universities, private tutors, and textbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://academicearth.org/
Similar to the Khan Academy, Academic Earth’s vision is to offer “a world-class education for everyone on earth“. The site offers free online classes and in-depth online learning through video lectures from university professors. Interestingly, Academic Earth has partnered with the same universities as Coursera and many more. In addition to Princeton, Stanford, and Berkeley, you will find video lectures from UCLA, Harvard, and Yale. Moreover, Academic Earth has partnered with the Khan Academy.

https://www.coursera.org/
Coursera has partnered with top US universities to provide some of their courses for free. The site offers lectures on computer science, healthcare, social sciences, and economics from universities like Princeton, Stanford or Berkeley.